# gDevilspie fails to launch, what to do?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, software-center, pygtk, gdevilspie

When launched from terminal:

```
---:~$ gdevilspie
pyGTK is not correctly installed, exiting.
```

Installed in 11.10 Using Ubuntu Software Center...
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug report http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=628492

suggests `python-glade2` is the missing dependency.

```
sudo apt-get install python-glade2
```

If that fixes the problem, you may wish to append your bug report on launchpad ;)

Comment: It fixed it, bug report amended, thanks for speedy reply,

Comment: Glad you got it working, thank you for the bug report and amending it.