# setup workspaces

Tags: workspace-switcher

I am loving the Ubuntu workspace swicther!

However, when I move my DVI cable from my laptop to my work PC (like what a KVM switch) would do all my screens get thrown around and when I come back I have to reposition all my windows.

Is there a way I can program which workspaces have which open windows. Ie Workspace 1 has chrome, workspace 2 has Sublime Text 3, Workspace 3 has PGAdmin3.

Also with dual screens my 9 workspaces each have two windows so I have maybe. I'd like to just 'click' and boom! all my programs open and are allocated to each workspace screen.

If anyone can point me in the right direction to get going on this that would be great. Anything to save the 5 mins it takes each time I want to set my workspaces up.

Comment: What about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206624/how-do-i-script-to-open-a-set-of-programs-each-on-specific-workspace

Comment: awesome thank you. Did not know the right keywords to search if the question had already been asked. Cheers.

Comment: Did @jmunsch 's solution work? This *opens* an application in a specific workspace, but your applications are getting thrown around after they are already open (I am having the same issue as you).