# Need to start Firefox on second display

Tags: boot, firefox, display

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04. I have a couple of issues I need resolved. Currently, I have Firefox in the startup folder. I am running a computer to a large TV screen that has a very high resolution. When the computer starts, it obviously boots Firefox immediately.

Here is what I need:

1. From startup, I need Firefox to open on the TV screen without being in full screen mode. I would like it to be the same size window every time that it opens.
2. I need my windows that open to stop going full screen automatically when they are dragged to the top of the screen and touch the edges of the screen.
3. I need to know why Adobe flash player will not download.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would like to figure this one out myself, but unfortunately, I don't know;
2. Assuming you use the Unity Interface, download the 'unity-tweak-tool' (if you use the Ubuntu Software Centre, lose the dashes). You can define the window snapping under the option, amazingly enough, Window Snapping. This tool is also great for tweaking other settings concerning the Unity Interface;
3. Have you installed the 'ubuntu-restricted-extras' package? It allows you to use Flash.

Edit:

1. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/235011/335497) seems like it could be a working solutions, but I haven't tried it myself, since I once messed up my system using 'compizconfig-settings-manager', although I just starting using Ubuntu/Linux at that point. Do be careful and don't mess with options you don't understand! :D

Comment: Any ideas for the first one?