# Making a webapp startup at specific workspace

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, startup, workspaces, webapps

I want some applications to startup when I login to my Ubuntu desktop account. A few of them are webapp shortcuts like Tweetdeck that I created from the Chrome web browser. I have no idea where it is stored on the hard drive or how it's called or how to find it, assuming that setting the full program name as command in the startup application window would start it up on login (like `thunderbird` launches Thunderbird).

Additionally I'd like each one of those programs to be displayed on a specific workspace (I use a 3*3 virtual desktop setting), like Tweetdeck showing on workspace 2 and Thunderbird showing on workspace 3. Preferably **without** the need of installing software, rather a script or extra command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome, open up tweetdeck. On the right-hand side of chrome, click the Menu button, then choose Settings.
In the settings tab, under "On Startup" choose "Continue where I left off"
You can close chrome, and re-open it to test. Now everytime chrome is started, it should have tweetdeck open, unless you close tweetdeck. Feel free to add other tabs or apps and it will open all those too.

From Dash Home start typing "Startup Applications" and click to open it.
Click on 'Add'.
Name it, browse for the command you want to open, add a comment if you wish.
In your case, browse to /usr/bin/ then click on "google-chrome", and hit the Open button

Now each time you startup, chrome will open, and when chrome opens, tweetdeck should be running.

I am not familiar with opening specific windows in specific workspaces, but I believe that is already answered here:
[How can I get a startup application to run in another workspace other than #1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87002/how-can-i-get-a-startup-application-to-run-in-another-workspace-other-than-1)
That describes a program called devilspie as well as the Compiz method

Script to run the shortcut:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app-id=hbdpomandigafcibbmofojjchbcdagbl --profile-directory=Default
exit 0
```

Comment: I just want the chrome web app to open in it's own window. Which it does normaly because I used chrome to create an (semi)independant web app. No browsable chrome browser appears, just the webapp. As for using the method you describe, I was looking for something more like a script I could create or a command that I can add to the 'command' section of the startup application window.

Comment: I use the tweetdeck extension in chrome, if you use something else, then this probably will not work for you. I do not know what you mean by 'web app' unless you mean the extension. Also not sure what you mean by a script, because that is what we are doing when adding an application to Startup Applications

Comment: Right-click the extension on the chrome app screen and select: create extension.

Comment: ah. i created shortcut, and looked at it. by rt clicking and selecting properties. it is running this: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app-id=h[edited]gbl --profile-directory=Default. I would make a bash script that ran this, then select that script in the Startup Applications. I will add a 3-line bash to my original post

Comment: It is 3 lines. Save it as something you will remember "tweetdeck.sh" for example. Make it executable: "chmod +x tweetdeck.sh" then use that in Startup Applications

Comment: Using your info I was able to find the extensions path (assuming thet your provided extention had a different name than mine) and added it right in the startup application windows' command box.

Comment: No, not yet. I prefer a method that doesn't need installing additional software. Your answer will be accepted by me as soon as I find an answer to my likings, or when there is no answer at all. Thanks

Comment: try the Compiz method on that page. No additional software needed as you probably are using it already. I am

Comment: It works partialy with compiz, thanks a lot. The only thing that doesn't work is an extension, like you also did with tweetdeck. Maybe I will find a workaround to use in tweetdeck.sh script.

Comment: Try wmctrl, I have seen people use that in shell scripts to choose the workspace to run a program in, like using export DISPLAY= will choose a certain monitor to run a program on in multi-display setups

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the compiz method works as a charm now. I needed to reboot instead of log out and back in.